# Why does Sieve behave strangely on a base64 subject line?

Tags: email, base64, sieve

I'm trying to get the message filtered by Sieve by the subject line:

```
Subject: =?utf-8?B?0K3Qu9C10LrRgtGA0L7QvdC90YvQuSDRh9C10Log0L/QviDQ?=
 =?utf-8?B?t9Cw0LrQsNC30YMgMTY5MzQwMTktMDA4Ng==?=
```

This filter does get the message discarded:

```
if header :contains "Subject" "0"
{
    discard;
}
```

but this one (or anything more complex) does not:

```
if header :contains "Subject" "L"
{
    discard;
}
```

How come Sieve thinks the subject line contains `0` but not `L`? Is there something fundamental I'm missing about Sieve and base64?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sieve scripts will decode `Subject` header into actual human-readable string before test them. So your code tests `0`/`L` against `Электронный чек по заказу 16934019-0086`, not `=?utf-8?B?...?=`. (Strictly speaking, the subject text breaks on the wrong place though)

[RFC5703 2.4.2.2](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5228#section-2.4.2.2)

> Interpretation of header data SHOULD be done according to [MIME3]
> section 6.2 (see section 2.7.2 below for details).

> [MIME3]     Moore, K., "MIME (Multipurpose Internet Mail Extensions)
> Part Three: Message Header Extensions for Non-ASCII
> Text", RFC 2047, November 1996.